# Which JDK is best suited for R3 Corda framework

Tags: corda

We are considering over which JDK is best suited for the R3 Corda.
However there is some incosistency in the way framework suggests the deployment.

1. Oracle JDK  – 
   Recommended as per the Corda documentation https://docs.corda.r3.com/getting-set-up.html
2. Open JDK –
   The Corda framework has a defined gradle task for docker deployment as “DockerForm”. This task generates the artifacts which are useful for deploying the Corda node as a docker container. So this task generates a Dockerfile for each node. This file is configured to use OpenJDK by default.

Please let us know the rationale behind this. Does Corda 3.x version support Open JDK as well? Do we have any guideline on which JDK to use in what situation?

Another concern is that eventually Oracle JDK will be a licensed product in future. So does R3 have any plans to support Open JDK as well in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3.1, Corda only supports the Oracle JDK 8 JVM, with a minimum supported version 8u171.

There is no current plans to add Open JDK support, but that could change (if, for example, Oracle JDK became a licensed product).

Comment: Thank you joel for quick clarification. Is there any specific reason why the DockerForm plugin is using OpenJDK version to generated DockerFile? I mean, is it just a consistency miss or a deliberate decision?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701777/why-dockerform-plugin-generates-docker-images-using-openjdk.