# Why "DockerForm" plugin generates Docker images using OpenJDK?

Tags: corda

Oracle JDK is recommended as per the Corda documentation. Corda does not officially support Open JDK.

Refer: [Which JDK is best suited for R3 Corda framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540401/which-jdk-is-best-suited-for-r3-corda-framework)

However if we use DockerForm to create Docker image for the Corda node, it internally uses OpenJDK.
Why is it so? I mean, is it just a consistency miss or a deliberate decision?

Answer (score 1):

The [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) that comes with the Oracle JDK does not allow for redistributing. So they cannot offer a Docker image with the Oracle JDK/JRE on it. You can, however, build one yourself and install Corda on that.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. The DockerForm actually generates DockerFile with openJDK option. The execution of DockerFile is anyway done by the user. I mean R3 is not distributing a ready Docker image for Corda node here. I think issue of re-distribution will happen if they were hosting a docker image. Sorry I am not a license expert. However kind of confused over this.